# Flutter Notification to Specific Users

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I have built a event app, where a user can book event. I want to provide notification to a user once they log-in, book an event, and a reminder notification. I have used Flutter Cloud Notification but that is only for push notification. Can Anyone help me out ?
I am using Flutter to build the application. Currently working on Android.

Tried with Flutter Cloud Messaging , but it will give only push notifications. But I need to send notification to a specific user, only when their application in the app gets approved.
Like User Applies for some internship => Gets approval from Admin => Gets a notification for 'Success'.

Comment: Exactly what kind of notifications do you need to send? what do you mean by "what is only for push notification"

Comment: I need to send notifications to specific users only. Here Push notification means that I create a notification and that is sent to every device which has the app downloaded.

Comment: To send a message to a specific device, you need to know that device's registration token. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/first-message.